# "Template argument 2 is invalid" while declaring vector

Tags: c++, templates

I am getting the error "Template argument 2 is invalid" when trying to declare a vector of ships. The error occurs on the following line:

```
vector<Ship> ships;
```

I am not yet using this vector anywhere or initializing it. How do I fix this error?

Here's my Ship class just to make sure:

```
class Ship {
public:
    Ship(char symb, PositionChar pos, char ori, unsigned int tam, unsigned int cor);
    //other methods
    bool move(char direction, bool rotate, unsigned int lineMin, unsigned int columnMin, unsigned int lineMax, unsigned int
        columnMax);

    bool moveRand(unsigned int lineMin, unsigned int columnMin, unsigned int lineMax, unsigned int columnMax);
    bool attack(size_t partNumber);
    bool isDestroyed() const;
    void show() const;
private:
    char symbol;
    PositionChar position;
    unsigned int size;
    unsigned int color;
    string status;
};
```

Comment: Please form an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and give the complete, exact error message. Maybe `Ship` is not defined. That's not the only possibility, though, and we have no way of knowing what the reason is for sure.

Comment: You are initializing it, that declaration calls the default constructor.

Comment: And while you're updating your question, include the *exact* error message *entirely* as presented with whatever toolchain you're using.

Comment: There could be another errors but the first thing I can see that you don't have default constructor.

Comment: @AshotKhachatryan that is very true and will cause future grief. Question for Verance: `vector<Ship> ships;` is in the Board class definition, yes? Do the Board and Ship classes have their own files, and if so, does Board's file include Ship's? If they are both defined in the same file, is Board defined before Ship?

Comment: Nope, I'm doing everything on the same file  by now. I solved this by putting the class Ship before the Board and it is working now :o

Comment: @AshotKhachatryan, [And?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d180e884b947c50)

Comment: Please don't treat the title as part of the question. People don't read the title as part of the question. Instead make sure that all relevant information is in the question body. Then add a title that describes your question in not too many words. Please edit in a MCVE that can be used to reproduce the error. Does the error also occur when you use an int instead for example? What can you remove out of Ship before the error disappears?